# Maintaining a ROS source install (add packages, update release)

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-hydro, osx, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bit of a follow up on the answer to this questions: http://answers.ros.org/question/108916/openni_launch-rosdep-on-os-x/

So assuming I have build and installed ROS (e.g. the desktop-full variant), I'm woundering how to best maintain my installation, meaning adding additional packages (which on ubuntu I would install via apt-get) and updating the whole installation to current releases (staying on the same distro, hydro in my case).

Is it possible and recommended to install to the same install space (e.g. /opt/ros/hydro) from different workspaces? E.g. I would like to add additional packages like suggested in the answer linked above. Can I build them in a freshly created workspace and install to /opt/ros/hydro? Should I instead extend my workspace with which I build the original packages installed to /opt/ros/hydro?

How would I go about upgrading my packages to the latest releases? Can I use my existing workspace and update the .rosinstall file to the latest released versions? What is the best practice here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109656/maintaining-a-ros-source-install-(add-packages,-update-release)./) by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4306 on 2013-12-12

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-16**:
Noone? There must be a ton of people having pure source-installs, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given that you have a base ROS installed, lets say to `~/hydro/install`, with the sources in `~/hydro/src`, which was generated from a `rosinstall_generator` command like `rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only > hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall`. In order to update this install I would do the following:

```
$ mv hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall.old
$ rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only > hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
$ diff hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall.old hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
```

On my machine I get something like this:

```
% diff hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall.old hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
412c412
<     version: release/hydro/orocos_kdl/1.2.0-1
---
>     version: release/hydro/orocos_kdl/1.2.1-0
952c952
<     version: release/hydro/urdf_tutorial/0.2.1-0
---
>     version: release/hydro/urdf_tutorial/0.2.2-0
956c956
<     version: release/hydro/urdfdom/0.2.8-1
---
>     version: release/hydro/urdfdom/0.2.10-3
```

This tells me that those three packages have new versions, then you can use `wstool` to update your `~/hydro/src` folder:

```
$ wstool merge -t src hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall

     Change details of element (Use --merge-keep or --merge-replace to change):
  orocos_kdl,  urdf_tutorial,  urdfdom

Continue: (y)es, (n)o, (v)erbosity, (a)dvanced options: y
Config changed, maybe you need run wstool update to update SCM entries.
Overwriting /Users/william/hydro/src/.rosinstall

update complete.
```

The above command will have updated the `.rosinstall` file in the `~/hydro/src` folder, grep shows me that orocos has indeed been updated:

```
% cat src/.rosinstall | grep orocos
- git: {local-name: orocos_kdl, uri: 'https://github.com/smits/orocos-kdl-release.git',
    version: release/hydro/orocos_kdl/1.2.1-0}
```

At this point though, you have not updated the source code you have, to do this you must use `wstool` again:

```
% wstool up -t src
```

The above command will check each entry in the `.rosinstall` against the thing in the source folder. When it finds an inconsistency, it will ask your what you want to do:

```
Prepare updating https://github.com/ros-gbp/catkin-release.git (version release/hydro/catkin/0.5.77-0) to /Users/william/hydro/src/catkin
Url https://github.com/ros/catkin does not match https://github.com/ros-gbp/catkin-release.git requested.
  (d)elete and replace, (a)bort, (b)ackup and replace, (s)kip: s
Skipping install of catkin because: Url https://github.com/ros/catkin does not match https://github.com/ros-gbp/catkin-release.git requested.
```

I have a custom version of `catkin` which I do not want to update, so I'll skip that one. Packages which are new will be fetched, I had removed opencv2, so it re-fetched that:

```
[opencv2] Fetching https://github.com/ros-gbp/opencv2-release.git (version release/hydro/opencv2/2.4.6-3) to /Users/william/hydro/src/opencv2
```

Finally it gets to `orocos_kdl` and updates it:

```
[orocos_kdl] Updating /Users/william/hydro/src/orocos_kdl
remote: Counting objects: 227, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (119/119), done.
remote: Total 189 (delta 66), reused 187 (delta 64)
Receiving objects: 100% (189/189), 20.61 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (66/66), completed with 16 local objects.
From https://github.com/smits/orocos-kdl-release
   b198d62..8909a85  debian/hydro/orocos_kdl -> origin/debian/hydro/orocos_kdl
   321632a..fa9be31  debian/hydro/precise/orocos_kdl -> origin/debian/hydro/precise/orocos_kdl
   eeb590d..e81a661  debian/hydro/precise/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/debian/hydro/precise/python_orocos_kdl
   aac5a5b..6f3732f  debian/hydro/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/debian/hydro/python_orocos_kdl
   707290a..43eb2ee  debian/hydro/quantal/orocos_kdl -> origin/debian/hydro/quantal/orocos_kdl
   784f63b..4b422b5  debian/hydro/quantal/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/debian/hydro/quantal/python_orocos_kdl
   9e30d46..be57517  debian/hydro/raring/orocos_kdl -> origin/debian/hydro/raring/orocos_kdl
   dd3ea36..83cb73b  debian/hydro/raring/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/debian/hydro/raring/python_orocos_kdl
   cd114b1..66acb41  master     -> origin/master
   3f2c2a6..82391b6  patches/debian/hydro/orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/debian/hydro/orocos_kdl
   b4da946..f2bd89f  patches/debian/hydro/precise/orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/debian/hydro/precise/orocos_kdl
   3e61cee..44e58b9  patches/debian/hydro/precise/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/debian/hydro/precise/python_orocos_kdl
   517103d..d44ddf6  patches/debian/hydro/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/debian/hydro/python_orocos_kdl
   02f4013..b2cf5d4  patches/debian/hydro/quantal/orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/debian/hydro/quantal/orocos_kdl
   9f1f5ec..67a0eac  patches/debian/hydro/quantal/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/debian/hydro/quantal/python_orocos_kdl
   7917a14..c038702  patches/debian/hydro/raring/orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/debian/hydro/raring/orocos_kdl
   5d92f2a..45fbe18  patches/debian/hydro/raring/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/debian/hydro/raring/python_orocos_kdl
   f9a1676..39b40d9  patches/release/hydro/orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/release/hydro/orocos_kdl
   f946058..71c4b15  patches/release/hydro/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/patches/release/hydro/python_orocos_kdl
   2d94e1c..2c5d3a2  release/hydro/orocos_kdl -> origin/release/hydro/orocos_kdl
   2468f71..84e236b  release/hydro/python_orocos_kdl -> origin/release/hydro/python_orocos_kdl
   bb592b5..ae2dc7c  upstream   -> origin/upstream
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-hydro-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_precise -> debian/ros-hydro-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_precise
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-hydro-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_quantal -> debian/ros-hydro-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_quantal
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-hydro-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_raring -> debian/ros-hydro-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_raring
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-hydro-python-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_precise -> debian/ros-hydro-python-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_precise
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-hydro-python-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_quantal -> debian/ros-hydro-python-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_quantal
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-hydro-python-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_raring -> debian/ros-hydro-python-orocos-kdl_1.2.1-0_raring
 * [new tag]         release/hydro/orocos_kdl/1.2.1-0 -> release/hydro/orocos_kdl/1.2.1-0
 * [new tag]         release/hydro/python_orocos_kdl/1.2.1-0 -> release/hydro/python_orocos_kdl/1.2.1-0
 * [new tag]         upstream/1.2.1 -> upstream/1.2.1
[orocos_kdl] Done.
```

Once that command finishes you can run `catkin_make_isolated --install --force-cmake` to rebuild and re-install the new and updated packages.

This is the workflow I would use if I just updated often, but I rebuild the whole thing so frequently that I just start with a fresh workspace.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-16**:
Thanks for you extensive answer. This almost fully answers my question. With this update model it seems fine to keep extending the workspace of the "base install" with additional stable packages (which i would otherwise want to install from a package manager).

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-16**:
However can you comment on installing an overlay into the same install space as the underlay (= base install)? See the third paragraph of my question.

**Comment by [jkolb](https://answers.ros.org/users/10551/jkolb/) on 2014-01-22**:
This should really be on the wiki and linked to from the source installation page.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-01-22**:
@jkolb: agreed, can you put it there? :-P
@William: any idea about reusing the underlays install space?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-24**:
I've added another section to the wiki with these instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-10**:
Regarding installing an overlay into the install space of an underlay. Conventional wisdom says it works: http://answers.ros.org/question/137121/installing-an-overlay-in-the-install-space-of-the-underlay

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When managing a large workspace, it gets awkward having to rebuild massive amounts of code every time you change one of the CMakeLists.txt files. I don't do anything as large as your source setup, but this works reasonably well for me:

1. Keep packages you are actively working on in a separate catkin workspace, overlaying to the main one.
2. Use `wstool update` to bring the latest sources into a given workspace, then rebuild it.

**UPDATE**: When building things from source in a catkin workspace, I normally run from that workspace. I generally only `make install` to verify that all the necessary files are being copied before releasing a package to the build farm.

- A command like `wstool set robot_model --version-new robot_model-1.7.1` will change an existing checkout to a different branch or tag. If needed, do that before running `wstool update`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-16**:
Yes, that makes sense. I am more concerned about the standard packages that I do not want to hack. I.e. I have the base install, and want to add another stable package from source and have it installed in /opt/... Have you ever installed and overlay to the install space of the base install?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-16**:
I guess the `wstool update` works only as wanted if the .rosinstall tracks e.g. the `devel-hydro` packages, but the `rosinstall_generator` (as used according to the install instructions in the wiki) tracks the release tags. Or am I mistaken? Can I switch to the latest release tags with `wstool`?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-01-22**:
Yes, `wstool set` allows you to change the version tag.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-01-22**:
Yes, but only if you know the tag you want. I was more concerned with getting the latest release for all the base packages, but William outlined a good way to handle it using `rosinstall_generator` and `wstool merge`.